# How to integrate line and area google chart in same chart

Tags: charts, line, composite, area

I need to make chart which have use same data and display line chart and area chart.How to 
 composite line and area chart.
       This is the data 
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses','Total'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400,600],
          ['2005',  1100,      200,900],
          ['2006',  6000,      5000,1000],
          ['2007',  1000,      500,500]

And i need sales and expenses line chart and total area chart.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333030/google-charts-hide-line-when-clicking-legend-key for show/hide

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761836/google-area-chart-variable-opacity-under-line can be useful for someone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [combo chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart). These are  A charts that lets you render each series as a different marker type from the following list: line, area, bars, candlesticks and stepped area.

To assign a default marker type for series, specify the seriesType property. Use the series property to specify properties of each series individually.

There is an [example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#combo_chart) in the link that you could edit. You used to be able to do a [compound chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/compound_charts) but these are sadly deprecated now.

example of area and line:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Total'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400,       600 ],
          ['2005',  1100,      200,       900 ],
          ['2006',  6000,      5000,      1000],
          ['2007',  1000,      500,       500 ],
        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
        ac.draw(data, {
          title : 'Sales & Expenses by Year',
          width: 600,
          height: 400,
          vAxis: {title: "Sales"},
          hAxis: {title: "Year"},
          seriesType: "area",
          series: {5: {type: "line"}}
        });
      }



      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

prints

[image: Sales and Expenses]